# Deleting content from media storage with React-Native-FS

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

Currently I am able to use `RNFS.unlink('file path')`, but this only deletes the file on disk.

How can I use RNFS to also delete the media content from the phone's gallery with a content path such as`'content://media/external/images/media/#####'`?

Comment: Did you try to use `RNFS.unlink('file path')` to delete any file on the content path yet? And it work?

Comment: I have, it throws an error saying that file does not exist.

Comment: Maybe the path uses to delete is not correct. Just suggest you use `readDir` method to get list file and delete it.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. That method does work. It seems that I was deleting the object reference before my async function got to deleting the content file.

Thanks Nguyên Hoàng!

Comment: @Progoogler I didn't understand when you said you were deleting the object reference before the async function got to delete the content file. could you elaborate this? I am facing the exact same problem.